# juju deploy ceph 'hook failed: "mon-relation-changed"'

Tags: juju, maas, ceph

I am running ubuntu 14.04.1 with juju 1.21.3 and deployed ceph to a machine with Intel Virtualization turned off in the bios.
It failed with `hook failed: "mon-relation-changed"`.
I rebooted the machine and fixed the bios setting and rebooted once again.   I then attempted to destroy-unit and destroy-machine.
The machine now says that it is dying, but everything is still running.
How do I force it to die so I can reinitialize the machine and try again?

Answer (score 1):

did you try `juju destroy-machine --force`?

To debug what happened when running the hook, try `juju debug-log`, or `juju ssh ceph/0` (or whatever the failing unit is), then look in `/var/log/juju` for a log file named after the service, that will show exactly why the hook failed.

Comment: It said the reason that it failed was because the physical machine didn't have Intel_Virtualization enabled in the bios.  That was easy to fix, recommission, and rebuild.

Comment: @DanielBidwell If you still have access to the log can you post an answer so if this is a problem for the next person we can have it documented? Or we can just close the question as too localized.